# Capturing mouse movement while mouse pressed in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mouselistener

This code worked a month ago.
However, I updated to a new version of flutter.
If you know in which version is needed or how I can implement it in the new version.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';    
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      // theme: design.getThemeData(),
      home: TestWidget(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    ),
  );
}

class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
      child: MouseRegion(
        onEnter: (ds) {
          print('Enterred:');
        },
        onExit: (ds) {
          print('Exit: ');
        },
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mouse Region](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MouseRegion-class.html) helps to capture events such as when the mouse enters, exits or hovers on a region of interest.

But for capturing the mouse location and mouse pressed or released within a region of interest (excluding mouse enter and mouse exit), you can use [Listener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Listener-class.html).

It gives callbacks separately for mouse press, release and move events. You can use these to achieve what you want.